# How to remove name of the input source on Mac and keep only the flag?

Tags: mac, keyboard, context-menu, input-languages

I have 2 input sources English(US) and Persian(Standard layout).

I used to be only seeing the flags while switching between these 2 keyboards. But after a while it's showing the name as well; and making the menu bar look cluttered (especially when it's on Persian), check out the image:
[image: here's the image of opened input source menu]

How do I remove the names from the menu bar and only keep the flags?

UPDATE: I'm using macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify which version of macOS you're using, but in Sierra, click on the Flag and select the "Hide Input Source Name" menu item.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I missed it! Is it added after Sierra?

Comment: No idea.  I don't actually use multiple languages.  Glad it solved your issue.